# How to use variable from another function in C?

Tags: c

I am new to C and am trying to use a variable from one function inside of another.

The function I declare the variable "grid" in is:

```
int startgame(int grid, int winlen)
{
  int failed = 0;
    if (grid < 4 || grid > 15){
    failed = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  if (winlen < 3 || winlen > grid){
    failed = 1;
    return 0;
  }
  if (failed == 0){
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I then want to use that variable grid in a second function. How do I do that?

Comment: Basically you don't. More context is needed about what you want to achieve. I.e. I think we are looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: You don't need to use the parameter  `grid` into another function. You probably need to use the value of `grid`. It now depends on the relationship between the two functions. If `startgame()` calls the other function then just pass `grid` as one of its parameters. If there is a third function that calls `startgame()` with arguments `a` and `b` then call the second function with `a` as one of its arguments. The value of `a` is copied into the parameter `grid` into `startgame()` and the same value reaches the second function in one of its parameters.

Comment: To get a helpful answer, please describe the second function. Write its header (the name and the arguments) and how do you want to call it and `startgame()`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this would be to declare the grid variable as an int pointer like this `int *grid;`, outside the function, and then pass it by reference to the startgame function. Still, you'd have to initialize that variable. That way, everything you do on it will be accessible even from outside when function finished executing.
You might want to read something about [pointers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm).

Comment: In this answer I miss the clarfication of what seems to be OPs confusion of "variable from this function" with "parameter given in from outside". Considering the "varaible" to have its source in this function is most likely what keeps OP form seeing a path to their goal.

Comment: By reading info on pointers, he will surely see the path to his goal. Grid variable in his example still doesn't have source in the function since it is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I know. You know. What I propose is to explain this in your answer, in a way that somebody who describes a parameter as "variable from this function" can understand.

Comment: I can't give a lecture on what C language is in a Stackoverflow answer to a code snippet, firstly because I am not capable of doing that, secondly because it won't really point OP in the right direction to solve his problem. I think as long as answers are not misleading, there's no reason to get cocky.

Comment: If you think that answering this question on OPs level is "a lecture on what C language is" then you should have asked for more focus (a close reason), for more details or clarity (a close reason) or for more context e.g. in MRE shape (could be seen as close reason). Some users did and closed this question. You did not and answered instead, which puts you in the privileged position of the only one who can answer here. Please do not retreat to saying that the question cannot be answered helpfully now.

Comment: I think I answered helpfully. If I see someone who wants to ask something about a problem they have, but they don't have the basic knowledge to actually formulate the question correctly, I'd still get to the point of his question instead of trying to correct every single mistake he may have done because of lack of knowledge. I don't want to argue with you, so please keep helping people in the way you think is feasible and let other people help in the way the think is correct.

Comment: Fair enough. Seems like a fish solution instead of a fishing solution to me however.

Comment: That's exactly what it is, since the question is circumscribed to a context and not spanning over the entire C language.